# How do you define per user routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create per user views in Rails and am trying to figure out the best way to define them in routes.rb. Say I wanted to have the following type of pathnames:

```
/users/1/event_list_view
/users/1/event_map_view
/users/1/aggregated_event_view
```

So the endpoint that comes after the '/users/1/' is not a resource, it's just another endpoint in the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def event_list_view
  end

  def event_map_view
  end

  def aggregated_event_view
  end
end
```

I tried a few different things, and currently have the following, but can't seem to get it to work:

```
  resources :users do
      match '/users/:id/event_list_view' => {:action=>"event_list_view", :controller=>"users"}
      match '/users/:id/event_map_view' => {:action=>"event_map_view", :controller=>"users"}
      match '/users/:id/aggregated_event_view' => {:action=>"aggregated_event_view", :controller=>"users"}
  end
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Member routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) should allow you to do what you want:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'event_list_view'
    get 'event_map_view' 
    get 'aggregated_event_view' 
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but it might also be worth considering alternative resource arrangements. If you're trying to show all the events associated with a user, it might make better sense to define an index route for the `Event` resource (etc, etc) and pass a user parameter there.

Comment: Ah, that totally makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanShih you bet. Good luck with your project!